# What's the difference between '--watchAll=false' and 'CI=true'?

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting up a CI using reactjs and I don't want the tests to run in watch mode.

In the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#on-your-own-environment) for running tests, it states the following:

*"By default npm test runs the watcher with interactive CLI. However, you can force it to run tests once and finish the process by setting an environment variable called CI."*

If, as stated, setting the 'CI=true':

*"The test command will force Jest to run in CI-mode, and tests will only run once instead of launching the watcher."*

Why does it (as quoted below) say **For non-CI environments**? Is there any reason you shouldn't use '--watchAll=false' in CI environments?

*"For non-CI environments, you can simply pass the --watchAll=false flag to disable test-watching."*

I've tried both in my CI environment and in my case both seems to work fine and doing the same thing. I would even prefer the '--watchAll=false', since this would be a more cross platform approach.

So, which one should I use in my CI environment and why? And also, what's the difference between the two of them?

Thank you!

Wondering which approach I should use 'CI=true' or '--watchAll=false'. I've tried both and they seem to be working in the same way.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#ci

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CI environment will likely set the CI environment variable to true without you doing anything.

So for your CI you shouldn't really need to set either `watchAll=false` or `CI=true` but if you do want to set something manually rather use CI=true.

At least one difference between the 2 is that `watchAll=false` (and if `CI=false`) will still create Jest snapshots if they don't exist. You won't want this in a CI environment. Your tests will pass even if the snapshots change.